# Django Meta.constraints are not working in my models

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, constraints

I'm trying to define a unique constraint for two primary keys in my model, because they are referenced by other models. And ent_ruc cant be unique. Must be unique together with ent_id.

```py
class Enterprise(models.Model):
    ent_id = models.CharField(
        db_column='ENT_ID', primary_key=True, max_length=16, default=timestamp_id_16)
    ent_ruc = models.CharField(
        db_column='ENT_RUC', max_length=16)
    ent_name = models.CharField(db_column='ENT_NAME', max_length=256)
    ent_address = models.CharField(db_column='ENT_ADDRESS', max_length=512)
    ent_type = models.CharField(db_column='ENT_TYPE', max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ENTERPRISE'
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=['ent_ruc', 'ent_id'], name='unique_enterprise')
        ]
```

But when I run the server I get the error:

'Enterprise.ent_ruc' must be unique because it is referenced by a foreign key.
HINT: Add unique=True to this field or add a UniqueConstraint (without condition) in the model Meta.constraints.

Why Meta.constraints are not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the constraints..

```
class Meta:
db_table = 'ENTERPRISE'
constraints = [
    models.UniqueConstraint(
        fields=['ent_ruc'], name='unique_ent_ruc'),
    models.UniqueConstraint(
        fields=['ent_id'], name='unique_ent_id')
]
```

Comment: Like I said, it can't be unique.

Comment: Try separating the constraints

Comment: that delete the error but now I get a error not related with this when I insert a Branch record. A Branch gets the primary keys from Enterprise.

Comment: ok, I fixed all. Django is great and awesome at almost all, but stupid in others.